# Issue processing PHP form checkboxes into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP form that uses checkboxes. I also have a MySQL database with 3 tables.

One of the tables is named TAGS and its columns are ID and ARTICLE_CONTENTS.

Another table in the database is called ARTICLES and its columns are ID, ARTICLETITLE, ARTICLEORGANIZATION, ARTICLEDATE, and ARTICLEURL.

The third table is called ARTICLES_TAGS and its columns are ARTICLE_ID and TAG_ID

The TAGS table has 87 entries that are similar to:

```
1    |    geology
2    |    astronomy
3    |    chemistry
```

The purpose of the database is to create relationships between the TAGS and the ARTICLES. To do this, the PHP form uses checkboxes that the user can check when adding a new entry to the database. These checkboxes represent the tags in the TAGS table. So, for example, there would be a checkbox for each entry in the TAGS table: [ ]geology    [ ]astronomy    [ ]chemistry ...etc...

What I'm trying to do is to insert information using text boxes (article title, article organization, article date, and article url) and to use mysql_insert_id() to get the ID of that insertion and to pair that ID with the ID of the tag associated with the checkboxes that are checked.

So, for instance, if the geology checkbox were to be checked and if, in the TAGS table the entry for geology were to be:

```
02  |  geology
```

And, if the ID for the article being inserted happened to be 142

Then

a new entry would be inserted into ARTICLES_TAGS:

```
Article_ID    |    TAG_ID
   142        |      02
```

However, whenever I execute my form I get no entries in the ARTICLES_TAGS table though the information INSERTs into the ARTICLES table properly. I can not figure out where I've gone wrong.

I've been working on the wording of this question for a few days and I think it's clear now. Please let me know if there needs to be any clarification.

The code is:

```
<?php
    function renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization, $articledate, $articleurl, $articletags )
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    . . .
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            . . .
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar1">
            . . .
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="stylized" class="myform">
                <form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Create a new entry in the database</h1>
                        <table width="76%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><legend></legend></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="20%" align="right"><span class="field">Article Title:</span></td>
                                <td width="80%" align="left"><span class="field">
                                    <input name="articletitle" type="text" value="<?php echo $articletitle; ?>" size="50"/>
                                </span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Author:</span></td>
                                <td align="left"><span class="field">
                                    <input name="articleorganization" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleorganization; ?>" size="50"/>
                                </span></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td align="right"><span class="field">Access Date:</span></td>
                                 <td align="left"><span class="field">
                                     <input name="articledate" type="text" value="MM/DD/YYYY" size="50"/>
                                 </span></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td align="right"><span class="field">Article URL:</span></td>
                                 <td align="left"><span class="field">
                                     <input name="articleurl" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleurl; ?>" size="50"/>
                                 </span></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Tags:</span></td>
                                 <td align="left"><span class="field">
                                     <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="1" id="articletags_0" />Science
                                     <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="2" id="articletags_1" />Geology

                                 </span></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add this Article" /></td>
                             </tr>
                        </table>
                </form>
        </div>
       <div class="footer">
           . . .
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
}
    include('settings.php');

    if(count($articletags) > 0)
{
    $articletags_string = implode(",", $articletags);
}
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{ 
    $articletitle = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articletitle']));
    $articleorganization = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleorganization']));
    $articledate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articledate']));
    $articleurl = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleurl']));
{
}
    if ($articletitle == '' || $articleorganization == '')
{
    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
    renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization);
}
    else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
        articleorganization='$articleorganization',
        articledate='$articledate',
        articleurl='$articleurl' ");
    $article_id = mysql_insert_id();       

    foreach ($_POST['articletags'] as $newtag)
{
    mysql_query(" INSERT INTO articles_tags article_id='$article_id',
               tag_id='$newtag' ");
}
    header("Location:addsuccess.php");  
}
}
    else
{
    renderForm('','','','','');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Getting it working...

Firstly, you've a parse error to fix.

#### Line 93:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
    articleorganization='$articleorganization',
    articledate='$articledate',
    articleurl='$articleurl' ")
    $article_id = mysql_insert_id();       
or die(mysql_error()); 
header("Location:addsuccess.php");
```

Note the `or die()` after the assignment of `$article_id = mysql_insert_id()`. This is invalid syntax.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
    articleorganization='$articleorganization',
    articledate='$articledate',
    articleurl='$articleurl' ")
    or die(mysql_error()); 
$article_id = mysql_insert_id();       
header("Location:addsuccess.php");
```

#### Line 84 - 85:

```
foreach( $POST_['articletags'] as $newtag )
{
}
```

This block is the problem: you have a loop doing nothing. However, you do have the insert statement ready to go. So let’s merge this loop with line 101 (at 101's position) to make a working insertion.

```
foreach( $_POST['articletags'] as $newtag )
{
  mysql_query('INSERT INTO articles_tags (article_id,tag_id) VALUES ($article_id, $newtag)');
}
```

Your result should look like this:

```
<?php
    function renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization, $articledate, $articleurl, $articletags )
{
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    . . .
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            . . .
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar1">
            . . .
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="stylized" class="myform">
                <form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
                    <h1>Create a new entry in the database</h1>
                        <table width="76%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><legend></legend></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="20%" align="right"><span class="field">Article Title:</span></td>
                                <td width="80%" align="left"><span class="field">
                                    <input name="articletitle" type="text" value="<?php echo $articletitle; ?>" size="50"/>
                                </span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Author:</span></td>
                                <td align="left"><span class="field">
                                    <input name="articleorganization" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleorganization; ?>" size="50"/>
                                </span></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td align="right"><span class="field">Access Date:</span></td>
                                 <td align="left"><span class="field">
                                     <input name="articledate" type="text" value="MM/DD/YYYY" size="50"/>
                                 </span></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td align="right"><span class="field">Article URL:</span></td>
                                 <td align="left"><span class="field">
                                     <input name="articleurl" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleurl; ?>" size="50"/>
                                 </span></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Tags:</span></td>
                                 <td align="left"><span class="field">
                                     <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="1" id="articletags_0" />Science
                                     <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="2" id="articletags_1" />Geology
                                 </span></td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                 <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add this Article" /></td>
                             </tr>
                        </table>
                </form>
        </div>
       <div class="footer">
           . . .
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php 
}
    include('settings.php');

    if(count($articletags) > 0)
    {
        $articletags_string = implode(",", $articletags);
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    { 
        $articletitle = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articletitle']));
        $articleorganization = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleorganization']));
        $articledate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articledate']));
        $articleurl = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleurl']));
        if ($articletitle == '' || $articleorganization == '')
        {
            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
            renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization);
        }
        else
        {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle',
                articleorganization='$articleorganization',
                articledate='$articledate',
                articleurl='$articleurl' ")
                or die(mysql_error()); 
            $article_id = mysql_insert_id();       
            header("Location:addsuccess.php");  
        }
        foreach( $_POST['articletags'] as $newtag )
        {
          mysql_query('INSERT INTO articles_tags (article_id,tag_id) VALUES ($article_id, $newtag)');
        }
    }
    else
    {
    renderForm('','','','','');
    }
?>
```

## Now that it works...

We've got to discuss security for just a second. You've done well so far for a beginner, but you've missed escaping one variable that gets inserted (verbatim!) into the queries: the tag_id. And you forgot that single-quotes do not insert values.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO articles_tags (article_id,tag_id) VALUES ($article_id, $newtag)');
```

Should really be (primarily for security):

```
mysql_query(sprintf('INSERT INTO articles_tags (article_id,tag_id) VALUES (%d, %d)', $article_id, $newtag));
```

### A little optimization

When you're inserting a lot of tags this script creates multiple queries. So I figured that I'd show you how to clean it up to insert multiple tags at once.

```
if(isset($POST_['articletags']) && count($POST_['articletags'])) {
  $query = 'INSERT INTO articles_tags (article_id,tag_id) VALUES ';
  $tags = array();
  foreach( $POST_['articletags'] as $newtag )
  {
    $tags[] = sprintf('(%d, %d)', $article_id);
  }
  mysql_query($query . implode(', ', $tags));
}
```

This code generates the same query as before, but it will build a set of lists to insert multiple entries at once. On top of that, it also filters both values into integers.

### Code formatting

I had to do a little reformatting to understand your code. This is partly the cause of your problem. Without proper indentation you might miss errors like this easily and never know. You might want to read up on [programming style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style).