# How to delete rows of database results using checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, sql-delete, administrator

I'm trying to delete rows of MySQL date using Checkboxes. When I apply the script below it doesn't do what I want it to do. Action is not performed.. And I get

`Undefined variable: checkbox in C:\wamp\www\project\topics.php on line 108`

I tried echoing out the actual sql that is being sent for execution and it gave  this

`DELETE FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_id = intval()`

**PHP**

```
<?php        

$topics = mysql_query(" SELECT topic_id , topic_head , 
                               topic_tags , topic_owner , topic_date
                        FROM   forum_topics ") or die (mysql_error());?>

         <form method='post' action='topics.php'>
             <div class='admin'><table>       
                        <tr>
                            <td >DELETE</td>
                            <td >ID</td>
                            <td>Title</td>
                            <td>Tags</td>
                            <td>Owner</td>
                            <td>Date</td>  
                        </tr>

                        <?php
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($topics)){ ?>
                   <tr align=center> 
                     <td align="center" bgcolor="black">
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['topic_id'];?>">
                </td>
                 <td><?php echo intval($row['ID']); ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['topic_head']); ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['topic_tags']); ?></td>
                 <td>><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['topic_owner']); ?></td>
               <td>
                            <?php           
                                  $date = date_create($row['topic_date']) ;
                                  echo  date_format($date, 'F j, Y, g:i A'); 
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <?php echo"
                        </tr>"; 
                        }?> 

         <td ><input name="delete" type="submit" value="DELETE"></td>
        <?php
         // Check if delete button active, start this
        if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
          for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ 
           $del_id = $checkbox[$i]; 
          $sql = "DELETE FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_id = intval($del_id)"; 
                  mysql_query($sql);
                 }   
               }
            ?>
                       </table>
                       </form>
                       </div>
```

Comment: Where do you specify `$checkbox`?

Comment: Yeah `$checkbox` appears out of no where

Comment: @ibu I have the checkbox in the <input> `<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['topic_id'];?>">`

Comment: You can develop your own solution by adapting my example on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123782/issue-processing-php-form-checkboxes-into-mysql-table/11124355#11124355

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you need to rewrite your deletion logic into something like this

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $del_id){
        $del_id = (int)$del_id;
        $sql = "DELETE FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_id = $del_id"; 
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
    header('Location: topics.php');
}
```

Also consider to do not use `mysql_*` functions since deprecation process has begun.

**EDIT** Added missed parenthesis in `if` condition

**EDIT** 
Also I recommend to redirect user to the same page after form submission it'll prevent from repeated form submits on page refresh. See updated code. And of course deletion logic should be placed before you made any selects

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. But I'm having to do the process twie, before it takes effect.

Comment: @DotOyes I guess you get all topics before deletion. Just put `DELETE` before your `SELECT`

Answer (score 2):

where are you getting the value from the array ??

you should have something like

```
$array = $_POST[checkbox];
```

then u can do the for

```
foreach($array as $delID){

          $sql = "DELETE FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_id = $delID"; 
                  mysql_query($sql);

}
```

the validation for num values do it before everything

Comment: watch this:  i change the value of the check box to `'1) OR 1'` and all your table data is deleted, [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: yes, thats the reason i told him ... validation before everything.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing these lines:

```
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ 
    $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
```

for this ones

```
 $count=count($_POST['checkbox']);
 for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){ 
    $del_id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
```

your `$checkbox` variable is supposed to work if php directive [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) is on, but that directive has been for a long time been default to off besides it's been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0 because of security related issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get an Undefined Offset on that line when I replaced with your code.

Comment: where is defined `$count` ? I dont see it in your code, it should be right above the `for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){` line, and be like `$count = count($_POST['checkbox']);`

Comment: I've **updated** my answer with the `$count` definition, try that.